# Direct link generation in activeadmin using a text input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I would like to create a quick link text input on the active admin landing page. The idea is that I'd like to create a small form on the dashboard page. The user enters an existing id into the text input and clicks the submit button. Based on the id entered, a direkt link to a resource is generated, based on the resource id entered. The resource is static, so just the id changes.
I have no idea if and how that's possible in activeadmin. So I'm more than happy about any suggestions and ideas on a possible implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example how you can build a Dashboard widget:
https://github.com/activeadmin/demo.activeadmin.info/blob/master/app/admin/dashboard.rb#L36

In the partial, you can build a inout and a button, with a javascript that opens the related page.

```
<input id="resource_id">
<input id="open_resource_id">
<script>
   $("#open_resource_id").click(function(){
     window.location = "/admin/RESOURCE_NAME/" + $("#resource_id").val();
   })
</script>
```